# how do i get .stop to work and make sure that the heading stops when i click and not where i click

Tags: javascript

How do I make .stop make the heading stop where I click. and not move due to animation. only using javascript. I need the heading to stop where i click but i need to click on the heading to make it stop so i cannot click anywhere and the heading move there then stop, stop when i click where the heading is at.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Interactive programming</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="heading" style="position:absolute;">Watch the moving heading!</h1>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <script>
    function move() {
      $("h1").animate({
          "left": "+=200px"
        }, "slow")
        .animate({
          "top": "+=200px"
        }, "slow")
        .animate({
          "left": "-=200px"
        }, "slow")
        .animate({
          "top": "-=200px"
        }, "slow", function() {
          setInterval(move(),300)
        });
    }
    setInterval(move(),300)
    //this should stop it
    $("h1").click(function() {
    $("h1").stop();
    })

  </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'setInterval' will keep running, so you will start a new animation after 300 ms, even though you call 'stop'.

The solution is to asssign 'setInterval' to a var, then you can call 'clearInterval'.

```
          var interval = setInterval(move(),300);
    });
}
var setinterval = setInterval(move(),300);
```

Now you can can stop the interval:

```
$("h1").click(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  $('h1').stop();
}
```